# How to pass a generic type not having a Interface to a Of T function

Tags: vb.net, generics, reflection, types

I have a following code which works fine

```
MsgBox(AddSomething(Of String)("Hello", "World"))

Public Function AddSomething(Of T)(ByVal FirstValue As T, ByVal SecondValue As T) As String
    Return FirstValue.ToString + SecondValue.ToString
End Function
```

Now we are redesigning the application to work with parameters of different types which will be provided through XML

```
  <SomeValues>
    <Add Param1="Somedata" Param2="SomeData" MyType="String"/>
    <Add Param1="Somedata" Param2="SomeData" MyType="MyBusinessObject"/>
  </SomeValues>
```

If I try to provide the following it gives error as Of accepts only type

```
    ''''Get DetailsFromXml --- MyType,Param1,Param2
    MsgBox(AddSomething(Of Type.GetType(MyType))(Param1,Param2))
```

How to solve this issue.

**Edit**

The above example is given to make the question simple. Actual issue is as follows 
I am using SCSF of P&P. 
Following is per view code which has to be written for each view

```
Private Sub tsStudentTableMenuClick()
    Dim _StudentTableListView As StudentListView
    _StudentTableListView = ShowViewInWorkspace(Of StudentListView)("StudentTable List", WorkspaceNames.RightWorkspace)
    _StudentTableListView.Show()
End Sub
```

Now I want to show the views dynamically.

```
 Public Sub ShowModalView(ByVal ViewName As String)
        Dim _MasterListView As >>>EmployeeListView<<<<
        _MasterListView = ShowViewInWorkspace(Of >>>EmployeeListView<<<)("Employee List", WorkspaceNames.RightWorkspace)
        _MasterListView.Show()
    End Sub
```

So the part shown using the arrows above has to be somehow dynamically provided.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The point of generics is to provide extra information at *compile-time*. You've only got that information at *execution-time*.

As you're using VB, you *may* be able to get away with turning `Option Strict` off to achieve late binding. I don't know whether you can turn it off for just a small piece of code - that would be the ideal, really.

Otherwise, and if you really can't get the information at compile-time, you'll need to call it with reflection - fetch the generic "blueprint" of the method, call [`MethodInfo.MakeGenericMethod`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.methodinfo.makegenericmethod.aspx) and then invoke it.

I assume that the real method is somewhat more complicated? After all, you can call `ToString()` on anything...

(It's possible that with .NET 4.0 you'll have more options. You could certainly use `dynamic` in C# 4.0, and I believe that VB10 will provide the same sort of functionality.)

Comment: Thanks for update. As you said the actual issue is not that simple. I have added actual issue in the question

Answer (score 2):

In .Net generics, you *must* be able to resolve to a specific type at *compile time*, so that it can generate appropriate code.  Any time you're using reflection, you're resolving the type at *run time*.

In this case, you're always just calling the `.ToString()` method.  If that's really all your code does, you could just change the parameter type to `Object` rather than use a generic method.  If it's a little more complicated, you could also try requiring your parameters to implement some common interface that you will define.

Answer (score 2):

If all you are doing is `ToString`, then making the parameters `object` instead would solve the problem in the simplest way. Otherwise you are going to have to bind the type at run-time, which in C# looks like:

```
System.Reflection.MethodInfo mi = GetType().GetMethod("AddSomething");
mi = mi.MakeGenericMethod(Type.GetType(MyType));
object result = mi.Invoke(this, new object[] { Param1, Param2 });
```

Because it involves reflection it won't be fast though... but I assume that's not a problem in this context.